# Performing a twitter search in python using Oauth

Tags: python, twitter

I'm just being a bit of an idiot here, I think, but I've figured out how to fetch my timeline, but not how to modify that into performing a search. I've currently got:

```
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
access_token = oauth.Token(key=ACCESS_KEY, secret=ACCESS_SECRET)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)

response, data = client.request(searchURL)
```

I'm guessing it's the last line that'll change to work with the search, but I'm not sure how to format it, if I change the searchURL to the one used for actually searching (it's currently on timeline) it says it's in the wrong format.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's off the form:

```
searchURL = https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=obama&count=2&tresult_type=popular
```

That's an example search using the keyword "obama", setting the count to 2, and filtering for popular results.

```
response, data = client.request(searchURL)

tweets = json.loads(data)
```

The format of the returned tweets is a bit...awkward, but understandable with a bit of playing around.